# Animation of double pendulum

Tags: differential-equations, animation, physics, simulation

Sadly, I am a completely newbie. I am studying Physics and in our theoretical physics class we got the task to solve the double pendulum using *Mathematica*. We just got the program, but no introduction how to use it. So I am trying to animate the parametric plot. Any ideas?

```
sol = NDSolve[{
  2*phi1''[t] + phi2''[t]*Cos[phi1[t] - phi2[t]] + 
    phi2'[t]^(2)*Sin[phi1[t] - phi2[t]] + 2*9.81*Sin[phi1[t]] == 
  phi2''[t] + phi1''[t]*Cos[phi1[t] - phi2[t]] - 
    phi1'[t]^(2)*Sin[phi1[t] - phi2[t]] + 9.81*Sin[phi2[t]] == 0, 
  phi1[0] == Pi/2, phi2[0] == Pi, phi1'[0] == 0, phi2'[0] == 0}, 
  {phi1[t], phi2[t], t}, {t, 0, 10}] 

Plot[{phi1[t], phi2[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 10}]

x1[t] := Evaluate[Sin[phi1[t]] /. sol]
y1[t] := Evaluate[-Cos[phi1[t]] /. sol]
x2[t] := Evaluate[Sin[phi1[t]] + Sin[phi2[t]] /. sol]
y2[t] := Evaluate[-(Cos[phi1[t]] + Cos[phi2[t]]) /. sol]

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{{x1[t], y1[t]}, {x2[t], y2[t]}} /. sol], {t, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: I see one equation that has two `==` in it. Probably two equations that you have inadvertently merged. Ans it may be that in `{phi1[t], phi2[t], t}` you may have to drop the `t` part.

Comment: Try this instead: `sol = NDSolve[{2*phi1''[t] + phi2''[t]*Cos[phi1[t] - phi2[t]] + 
     phi2'[t]^(2)*Sin[phi1[t] - phi2[t]] + 2*9.81*Sin[phi1[t]] == 0, 
   phi2''[t] + phi1''[t]*Cos[phi1[t] - phi2[t]] - 
     phi1'[t]^(2)*Sin[phi1[t] - phi2[t]] + 9.81*Sin[phi2[t]] == 0,
   phi1[0] == Pi/2,
   phi2[0] == Pi,
   phi1'[0] == 0,
   phi2'[0] == 0}, {phi1[t], phi2[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]`. Since this seems to be a case of a simple error I'm going to vote  to close this question (no worries, nothing negative).

Comment: For a great introduction to Mathematica, have a look at Leonid Shifrin's free [book](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/). An extensive overview of additional Mathematica material can be found [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice/259#259).

Comment: `x1[t] := Evaluate[Sin[phi1[t]] /. sol]` should be `x1[t_] = Evaluate[Sin[phi1[t]] /. sol]`. And `y1`,`x2`, and `y2` should be similarly changed. `ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{{x1[t], y1[t]}, {x2[t], y2[t]}} /. sol], {t, 0, 10}]` should be `ParametricPlot[{{x1[t], y1[t]}, {x2[t], y2[t]}}], {t, 0, 10}]`

Comment: You'll probably get more meaningful graphical results if you use a dynamic rather than a static plot. E.g.: `Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{{x1[t], y1[t]}, {x2[t], y2[t]}}], {t, 0, s},
   PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 1.5}}], {{s, 0.00001}, 0, 10}]`

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I didn't feel like the typos alone justify closing the question because it's actual aim is to produce an animation.

Comment: @murray I just saw your comment after I posted an answer, basically saying the same thing - except I used `ListAnimate`...

Comment: @jens I somehow managed to not note that :-(. Retracted my close vote. Nice answer BTW.

Answer (score 58):

After correcting the syntax errors in the original code, the actual question can be addressed:

How to display the four variables `x1[t]...y2[t]` as an **animation** in a way that conveys their meaning? The basic idea is to use `ListAnimate` on a list of `frames` that I define below:

```
Clear[phi1, phi2, t];
sol = First[
   NDSolve[{2*phi1''[t] + phi2''[t]*Cos[phi1[t] - phi2[t]] + 
       phi2'[t]^(2)*Sin[phi1[t] - phi2[t]] + 2*9.81*Sin[phi1[t]] == 0,
      phi2''[t] + phi1''[t]*Cos[phi1[t] - phi2[t]] - 
       phi1'[t]^(2)*Sin[phi1[t] - phi2[t]] + 9.81*Sin[phi2[t]] == 0, 
     phi1[0] == Pi/2, phi2[0] == Pi, phi1'[0] == 0, 
     phi2'[0] == 0}, {phi1[t], phi2[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]];

x1[t_] := Evaluate[Sin[phi1[t]] /. sol]
y1[t_] := Evaluate[-Cos[phi1[t]] /. sol]
x2[t_] := Evaluate[Sin[phi1[t]] + Sin[phi2[t]] /. sol]
y2[t_] := Evaluate[-(Cos[phi1[t]] + Cos[phi2[t]]) /. sol]

frames = Table[
   Graphics[{Gray, Thick, 
     Line[{{0, 0}, {x1[t], y1[t]}, {x2[t], y2[t]}}], Darker[Blue], 
     Disk[{0, 0}, .1], Darker[Red], Disk[{x1[t], y1[t]}, .1], 
     Disk[{x2[t], y2[t]}, .1]}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-2.5, 2.5}, {-2.5, 2.5}}],
   {t, 0, 10, .1}];
ListAnimate[frames]
```

[image: animation]

The list `frames` is generated in a `Table` where the time `t` is incremented in steps of `.1` through the interval of the `NDSolve` solution. The drawing depicts the two xy coordinates as red disks, connected to each other and to the origin (the pivot) by gray lines. These are the rigid rods connecting the masses.

In terms of code, I changed the definition of `sol` to remove one level of `List` so that the resulting definition of the coordinate functions doesn't end up returning lists, but numbers. These coordinate definitions should also have a `t_` instead of `x1[t]` etc. to be consistent with the meaning of the `:=` (`SetDelayed`) in their definition (alternatively one could also have done those definitions in a simpler way without `:=`).

**Edit: more general solution**

To get more out of this animation, it may be of interest to change the simulation so that it can handle different masses, and different pendulum lengths. But this means you need to understand how the differential equation must be modified. For many constrained mechanics problems, including the double pendulum, the [Lagrange formalism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics) is the most efficient way to set up the equations of motion. *Mathematica* has a [`VariationalMethods`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/VariationalMethods/guide/VariationalMethodsPackage.html) package that helps to automate most of the steps. This is *extremely useful* for solving mechanics problems because it lets you focus on the physics while taking over the mathematical work of getting from the physics to the equations of motion.

Here is how it works. The following few lines contain **all the steps** from defining the variables to establishing and then solving the equations of motion, with arbitrary parameters for the pendulum geometry. Here `s1`, `s2` are the lengths of the two rods connecting the masses `m1`, `m2`. Most of the following equations can be done entirely in terms of the vectorial positions `r1` and `r2` without thinking about their components too much. The actual variables we solve for are `ϕ1, ϕ2`. To show the effect of doubling one of the masses and halving one of the pendulum rods, I then set those variables before calling `NDSolve`:

```
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]

Clear[s1, s2, ϕ1, ϕ2, t, g, m1, m2];
variables = {ϕ1[t], ϕ2[t]};
r1 = s1 {Sin[ϕ1[t]], -Cos[ϕ1[t]]};
r2 = r1 + s2 {Sin[ϕ2[t]], -Cos[ϕ2[t]]};

lagrangian = 
  m1/2 D[r1, t].D[r1, t] + m2/2 D[r2, t].D[r2, t] - 
   g {0, 1}.(m1 r1 + m2 r2);
eqs = EulerEquations[lagrangian, variables, t];

s1 = 1;
s2 = 1/2;
m1 = 2;
m2 = 1;
g = 9.81;
tMax = 10;
initial = {ϕ1[0] == Pi/2, ϕ2[0] == Pi, 
           ϕ1'[0] == Pi/2, ϕ2'[0] == 0};
sol = First[NDSolve[Join[eqs, initial], variables, {t, 0, tMax}]];    
nFrames = 100;
frames = Table[Graphics[{Gray, Thick,
      Line[{{0, 0}, r1, r2}],
      Darker[Blue], Disk[{0, 0}, .1],
      Darker[Red], Disk[r1, m1/10], Disk[r2, m2/10]} /. sol,
    PlotRange -> {{-2.5, 2.5}, {-2.5, 2.5}},
    Background -> Lighter[Cyan]], 
  {t, tMax/nFrames, tMax, tMax/nFrames}];
ListAnimate[frames]
```

[image: animations 2]

Note that the differential equations we're solving are never written down by hand anywhere. They are automatically generated by `EulerEquations`.

**Edit**

As requested in the comment, the solution above can also be re-used to plot a trace of the trajectory together with the pendulum graphic:

```
traceFrames = 
  Map[ParametricPlot[r2 /. sol, {t, 0, #}, 
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Lighter[Purple]], 
     PlotPoints -> Floor[(2 nFrames #)/tMax], 
     PlotRange -> {{-2.5, 2.5}, {-2.5, 2.5}}, 
     Background -> Lighter[Cyan]] &, 
   Range[tMax/nFrames, tMax, tMax/nFrames]];

ListAnimate[MapThread[Show, {traceFrames, frames}]]
```

[image: trace]

Here I re-use the list of `frames` from above and `Show` it together with a new list `traceFrames` in which the `ParametricPlot` of the end point `r2` is shown up to the intermediate time corresponding to the instants used in `frame`. Since `ParametricPlot` uses interpolation, we have to make sure that the plots for long times don't lose details, by increasing the number of `PlotPoints` with time.

Comment: Thank you very very much!

Comment: @Jens : I wonder how it is possible to add the trajectory of the pendulum ( I mean the trajectory of the red disks in the animations ) into the animation.Could you please help me ?

Comment: I believe ListAnimate[] defaults to a scene-length of 5 seconds, no matter how many frames are rendered. As the rendered frames stretch from t=0 to t=10, the animation is actually displaying at twice the physical speed.

Comment: @SebastianHenckel That's correct - if you want the movie to run at the actual speed of the motion, you have to play with the fps and duration. If you have a suggestion for how best to do it, I can add it.

Comment: Great answer!  And the first time I've seen it.  I added the simulation tag as I think your second section takes beyond mere animation.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks - and you're right about the tag, of course.

Comment: @Jens about the animation speed: specify `nFrames = 10*tMax;` and include `AnimationRate -> 10` in `ListAnimate`.

Comment: Great answer. I reformatted your code a bit to simulate an n-tuple pendulum and it works nicely. If anyone is interested I can post it as an answer.

Comment: @shrx.I am interested of yours solutions n-tuples pendulum.

Comment: @shrx Sure, go ahead and add an answer - and thanks for the suggestion regarding frame rate.

Answer (score 10):

This is not a direct answer to your problem, but rather a generalization of @Jens' code from double to n-tuple pendulums. Meaning you can also use it for double pendulums if you like. I'm providing it due to popular demand.

```
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]

n = 10; (* number of pendulum segments *)
rate = 10; (* animation frame rate *)
Clear[s, ϕ, t, g, m];
variables = ϕ[#][t] & /@ Range[n];
r[1] = s[1] {Sin[ϕ[1][t]], -Cos[ϕ[1][t]]};
For[i = 2, i <= n, i++,
 r[i] = r[i - 1] + s[i] {Sin[ϕ[i][t]], -Cos[ϕ[i][t]]};
 ]
lagrangian = 
  Sum[m[i]/2 D[r[i], t].D[r[i], t], {i, n}] - 
   g {0, 1}.(Sum[m[i] r[i], {i, n}]);
eqs = EulerEquations[lagrangian, variables, t];

(s[#] = 1) & /@ Range[n]; (* this is a placeholder, you can still specify individual *)
(m[#] = 1) & /@ Range[n]; (* lengths and masses *)
g = 9.81;
tMax = 10;
initial = {Sequence @@ ((ϕ[#][0] == Pi/2) & /@ Range[n]), 
   Sequence @@ ((ϕ[#]'[0] == 0) & /@ Range[n])};

sol = First[
   NDSolve[Join[eqs, initial], variables, {t, 0, tMax}, 
    Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]];

nFrames = tMax*rate;
frames = Table[
   Graphics[{Gray, Thick, 
      Line[{{0, 0}, Sequence @@ (r[#] & /@ Range[n])}], Darker[Blue], 
      Disk[{0, 0}, .1], Darker[Red], 
      Sequence @@ (Disk[r[#], m[#]/10] & /@ Range[n])} /. sol, 
    PlotRange -> {{-(n + 1), n + 1}, {-(n + 1), (n + 1)/2}}, 
    Background -> Lighter[Cyan]], {t, tMax/nFrames, tMax, 
    tMax/nFrames}];
traceFrames = 
  Map[ParametricPlot[r[n] /. sol, {t, 0, #}, 
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Lighter[Purple]], 
     PlotPoints -> Floor[(2 nFrames #)/tMax], 
     PlotRange -> {{-(n + 1), n + 1}, {-(n + 1), (n + 1)/2}}, 
     Background -> Lighter[Cyan]] &, 
   Range[tMax/nFrames, tMax, tMax/nFrames]];

ListAnimate[MapThread[Show, {traceFrames, frames}], 
 AnimationRate -> rate, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

This is a trajectory of a pendulum with 10 segments of equal lengths and masses right at the time it completes its first swing:

[image: pendulum trajectory]

Now, if you want, you can further expand the code to include perhaps drag or spring forces between the segments.

Answer (score 1):

I just modified the code in the graphic part so that it adapts to the different values of S1 and S2, since when establishing values higher than 2.5, the pendulums were no longer visible.

```
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]

Clear[s1, s2, \[Phi]1, \[Phi]2, t, g, m1, m2];
variables = {\[Phi]1[t], \[Phi]2[t]};
r1 = s1 {Sin[\[Phi]1[t]], -Cos[\[Phi]1[t]]};
r2 = r1 + s2 {Sin[\[Phi]2[t]], -Cos[\[Phi]2[t]]};

lagrangian = 
  m1/2 D[r1, t].D[r1, t] + m2/2 D[r2, t].D[r2, t] - 
   g {0, 1}.(m1 r1 + m2 r2);
eqs = EulerEquations[lagrangian, variables, t];

s1 = 4;
s2 = 4;
m1 = 3;
m2 = 6;
g = 9.81;
tMax = 10;
initial = {\[Phi]1[0] == Pi/2, \[Phi]2[0] == Pi, \[Phi]1'[0] == 
    Pi/2, \[Phi]2'[0] == 0};
sol = First[NDSolve[Join[eqs, initial], variables, {t, 0, tMax}]];
nFrames = 100;
frames = Table[
   Graphics[{Gray, Thick, Line[{{0, 0}, r1, r2}], Darker[Blue], 
      Disk[{0, 0}, .1], Darker[Red], Disk[r1, m1/10], Darker[Blue], 
      Disk[r2, m2/10]} /. sol, 
    PlotRange -> {{-(s1 + s2 + 1), (s1 + s2 + 
         1)}, {-(s1 + s2 + 1), (s1 + s2 + 1)}}, 
    Background -> Lighter[Cyan]], {t, tMax/nFrames, tMax, 
    tMax/nFrames}];
traceFrames = 
  Map[ParametricPlot[r2 /. sol, {t, 0, #}, 
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Lighter[Blue]], 
     PlotPoints -> Floor[(2 nFrames #)/tMax], 
     PlotRange -> {{-(s1 + s2 + 1), (s1 + s2 + 
          1)}, {-(s1 + s2 + 1), (s1 + s2 + 1)}}, 
     Background -> Lighter[Yellow]] &, 
   Range[tMax/nFrames, tMax, tMax/nFrames]];
ListAnimate[MapThread[Show, {traceFrames, frames}]]
```

[image: Graph without limitations of S1 and S2]